# Distribute private Android app through Google Play without EMM

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play, visual-studio-app-center

We have an app that we distribute to under 100 users in about 20 customer organizations. At the moment we the newest apk -file is just published to a url.

We are trying to use MS AppCenter distribution and that is working pretty nicely except for the initial install when the app is opening a webpage for distribution enrollment and the the app is not always reopened.

Is there a way to publish an app to Google Play as a "private" app so that you don't find it in Google Play search or lists but have to have the url to app to access it the first time?

Our customers don't have EMM.

Comment: It's not the best solution but you can use private alpha/beta tests on google play store.

Comment: [Private apps](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6145139?hl=en)?